# How does MSDTC work in Websphere Mq v.7.5.2.?

Tags: transactions, ibm-mq, msdtc

I am upgrading a Websphere v.7.0 C# client to v.7.5.2 primarily to take advantage of the new MSDTC feature. However my initial PoC'ing has revealed a number of issues, one of which is how transactions are committed and rolled back.

In v.7.0 commits and rollbacks was done synchronously, however v.7.5.2 using MSDTC, commits and rollbacks are done asynchronously.

This is a breaking change, so my question is:

1. Is there some sort of WaitHandle so you can get, to wait for the Commit or Rollback to complete?
2. Is there an option you can set, that will make the MSDTC commit and rollback synchrone?

Thanks
Slind

Answer (score 1):

At MQ v7.5, if you are using Global Transactions (XA), then the transactions are coordinated by MSDTC which decides when to commit or rollback a transaction. You may look at [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un11380_.htm) link that explains behavior further.

Transaction completed event can be handled in your application to know when a transaction is completed. Please see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioncompletedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it is not MSDTC who is ruining the show. It is the Mq Transaction manager who issues the async rollback when the DTC request it to rollback. So the DTC "think" i is rolled back, but the mq is still processing the request on a different thread